# Scrapy: USER_AGENT and ROBOTSTXT_OBEY are properly set, but I still get error 403

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler, agent

Hello and thanks in advance for the help or direction you can bring. This is my scraper:

```
import scrapy    
class RakutenSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "rak"
    allowed_domains = ["rakuten.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.rakuten.com/deals?omadtrack=hp_deals_viewmore']
    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="page-bottom"]/div'):
            yield {
                'titles': sel.xpath("//div[@class='slider-prod-title']").extract_first(),
                'prices': sel.xpath("//span[@class='price-bold']").extract_first(),
                'images': sel.xpath("//div[@class='deal-img']/img").extract_first()
            }
```

And this is part of my settings.py

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 5
# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = 'False'
```

and this is part of the log:

```
DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET https://www.rakuten.com/deals?omadtrack=hp_deals_viewmore> (referer: None)
```

I have tried almost all solutions I found in s/o

---

log file: This is a new log after installing Firefox driver. Now I get an **ERROR: Error downloading https://www.rakuten.com/deals?omadtrack=hp_deals_viewmore>**

```
2017-11-17 00:38:45 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2017-11-17 00:38:45 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'deals.spiders', 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['deals.spiders'], 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36', 'TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED': False, 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 5}
2017-11-17 00:38:45 [py.warnings] WARNING: :0: UserWarning: You do not have a working installation of the service_identity module: 'No module named cryptography.x509'.  Please install it from <https://pypi.python.org/pypi/service_identity> and make sure all of its dependencies are satisfied.  Without the service_identity module and a recent enough pyOpenSSL to support it, Twisted can perform only rudimentary TLS client hostname verification.  Many valid certificate/hostname mappings may be rejected.

2017-11-17 00:38:45 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-11-17 00:38:45 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['deals.middlewares.JSMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-11-17 00:38:45 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-11-17 00:38:45 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-11-17 00:38:45 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-11-17 00:38:45 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-11-17 00:38:45 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://www.rakuten.com/deals?omadtrack=hp_deals_viewmore>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1128, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 37, in process_request
    response = yield method(request=request, spider=spider)
  File "/home/seealldeals/tmp/scrapy/deals/deals/middlewares.py", line 63, in process_request
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 144, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
2017-11-17 00:38:45 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-11-17 00:38:45 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 1,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/exceptions.OSError': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 17, 5, 38, 45, 328366),
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'log_count/WARNING': 1,
 'memusage/max': 33509376,
 'memusage/startup': 33509376,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 17, 5, 38, 45, 112667)}
2017-11-17 00:38:45 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: 1) Your code works fine. I get 200 http code. You should use any proxy or crawlera, if you use scrapinghub.
If you need values but not selectors, use /text() and @src

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/tt3rO

Comment: Is there a way to see what has been sent to in the header to make sure my scrapy is sending the proper user agent

Comment: @eLRuLL I updated the question with the log file. what version of scrapy and python are you using

Comment: Are you able to access that page from your browser?, if not most likely your ip was banned.

Comment: I have tested that

Comment: already did https://imgur.com/a/tt3rO

Answer (score 4):

### What's wrong

- `rakuten.com` had integrated with `Google Analytics` which has anti-spider feature.
- If your request can't process `rakuten.com`'s `analytics.js` properly, you will be blocked from the site and have a `403` error code.

### How to fix it

> Use Javascript rendering technique

- Solution 1: (Integrate scrapy with scrapy-splash)

  - [Here is Scrapy-splash github repository](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash)
  - Install scrapy-splash from pypi:

    ```
    pip install scrapy-splash
    ```
  - [Install Docker to your machine](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/)
  - Run a scrapy-splash container:

    ```
    docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash
    ```
  - Add following lines to your `settings.py`

    ```
    SPLASH_URL = 'http://192.168.59.103:8050'
    ```
  - Append splash download middleware to your `settings.py`

    ```
    DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
        'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
        'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
        'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
    }
    ```
  - Change your spider's code to

    ```
    import scrapy    
    from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


    class RakutenSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "rak"
        allowed_domains = ["rakuten.com"]
        start_urls = ['https://www.rakuten.com/deals?omadtrack=hp_deals_viewmore']

        def start_requests(self):
            for url in self.start_urls:
                yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, args={'wait': 0.5})

        def parse(self, response):
            for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="page-bottom"]/div'):
                yield {
                    'titles': sel.xpath("//div[@class='slider-prod-title']").extract_first(),
                    'prices': sel.xpath("//span[@class='price-bold']").extract_first(),
                    'images': sel.xpath("//div[@class='deal-img']/img").extract_first()
                }
    ```
- Solution 2: (Integrate scrapy with selenium webdriver as a middleware)

  - [Selenium web driver python binding documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io)
  - Install Selenium from pypi:

    ```
    pip install selenium
    ```
  - If you want to use `Firefox` Browser, Install Firefox's Geckodriver to your `PATH`.

    - [Download Mozilla Geckodriver here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.19.1)
  - If you want to use `Chrome` Browser, Install Chrome driver to your `PATH`.

    - [Download Chromedriver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.33/)
  - If you want to use `PhantomJS` Browser, Install `phantomJS` from `Homebrew`.

    ```
       brew install phantomjs
    ```
  - Add a `JSmiddleware` class to your `middlewares.py`

    ```
        from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
        from selenium import webdriver


        class JSMiddleware(object):
            def process_request(self, request, spider):
                driver = webdriver.Firefox()
                driver.get(request.url)

                body = driver.page_source
                return HtmlResponse(driver.current_url, body=body, encoding='utf-8', request=request)
    ```
  - Append `selenium download middleware` to your `settings.py`

    ```
        DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
            'youproject.middlewares.JSMiddleware': 200
        }
    ```
  - Use your original spider's code

    ```
        import scrapy    


        class RakutenSpider(scrapy.Spider):
            name = "rak"
            allowed_domains = ["rakuten.com"]
            start_urls = ['https://www.rakuten.com/deals?omadtrack=hp_deals_viewmore']

            def parse(self, response):
                for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="page-bottom"]/div'):
                    yield {
                        'titles': sel.xpath("//div[@class='slider-prod-title']").extract_first(),
                        'prices': sel.xpath("//span[@class='price-bold']").extract_first(),
                        'images': sel.xpath("//div[@class='deal-img']/img").extract_first()
                    }
    ```

### More

- If you wan to use `Chrome` Browser with `Headless` mode, [check this tutorial](https://duo.com/blog/driving-headless-chrome-with-python)

Comment: You may be right it is a automated ban due to lack of javascript/flash. I just blocked javascript on my browser on my windows machine and got banned on the second request.

Comment: I followed step one with no luck. I may need to wait until my ban is lifted.

Comment: Ok I followed solution 2 and install geckodriver export PATH=$PATH://usr/local/bin/geckodriver .  Now I get an error. I updated the log file in the original question

Comment: This is the right answer. I've been running several tests and tried lots of options from scrapy docs but no luck. But now this explains a lot of this behavior.

Comment: @user8389458 Why SPLASH_URL = 'http://192.168.59.103:8050' address?

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with your settings, it should be:

```
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```

the `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY` variable needs a boolean, you were setting it with string. You can check your logs, that it was visiting the `robots.txt` request first.

Comment: Well I tried this early False and True as boolean and tried again now but I still see the same results.

Comment: All the testing were done on my remote Ubuntu server. When i use this code on my windows machine on a different IP it works. Is there a line command to test to see if my IP is banned

Comment: this is an interesting page, as you are not actually banned, but kind of the type of requests you are doing, because I bet you can still check that url in the browser, so I would say the request can still be improved. About checking if you are "banned", there is no "line command" to test that. Only that domain knows that, and depending on what they thing a "ban" is, they give you a custom response (403 on this case).

Comment: It seems to have some sort of algorithm to identify bot (Javascript/Flash disable)